# White footer under footer when hosted online but not in localhost

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome, footer

There's a mysterious white area under the footer in almost all bootstrap themes when viewed from Google Chrome but it doesn't show up when viewing from Internet Explorer or Mozilla firefox.

**For e.g http://webthemez.com/demo/mentor-free-html5-bootstrap-coming-soon-template/**

But this white area under footer doesn't show up in the same theme above in localhost even from chrome.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Seems working to me. I don't see any white area below the red footer from the given link. Do you have something active from your devtools? Device emulation e.g.?

Comment: http://fourgrafx.com/braink/multipage/ and this one? I have added the screenshot of the same.

Comment: that white area between task bar and the black of the theme.However the previous one seems to be fine now but i'm getting this in all bootstrap themes.

Comment: it's coming again..odd...

Comment: Sorry, they look fine to me too.